# How to disable model validation pass check when showing a disabled element in simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I use Ruby On Rails in combination with the Simple Form gem.

My validations in model looks like this

```
validates :name, presence: true
```

If I now have a disable input field for the name, then SimpleForm places the green checkmark (saying that the field content is correct) into the input field. Though I like this feature for enabled input fields, it is not required when a disabled input field is displayed.

Any way of deactivating this?